# How To JOIN TWO Table in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am USING THIS CODE FOr TWO Table Join and Show to DataGridView

```
Dim strSQL4 

strSQL4 = " Select Regno, Sname,Class, Section,SUM(FeeAmount) as FeeAmount FROM FeesMaster WHERE class='" & cboClass.Text & "'  GROUP By Regno,Sname,Class,Section"

strSQL5 = " Select Regno, ST_Name,Class, Section,SUM(Amount_Paid) as Amount_Paid FROM Fees_Transaction WHERE class='" & cboClass.Text & "'  GROUP By Regno,ST_Name,Class,Section"

Dim DaAp4 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL4, con)
Dim DSet4 As New DataTable
DaAp4.Fill(DSet4)
DataGridView2.DataSource = DSet4.DefaultView
```

Comment: I think you should do the join in the query, instead of having two separate queries.

Comment: I Use JOIN Query But That Amount Sum Proble..

Comment: hi guys if the connection string is different how he can join in a query. means from different servers data is collecting if so we cant join in a single query. may be he use tables from different servers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you're not actually doing anything with strSQL5, so how do you expect it to be present on the DGV?

as@xfx suggested, you should adapt strSQL4 so that it uses the SQL from strSQL5 as a JOIN.